# How to send multiple files to Github?

Tags: javascript, java, php, git, github

How do I send multiples files in subdirectories to github?

I want to send my project complete, but I can not!

I am using:

```
git add .
git commit -m "Coment"
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: do you add the remote as origin? what error comes up?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have set git remote URL correctly. You can check by using following command:

```
git remote -v
```

If not you can set using the following command:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git
```

or for https

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git
```